# Function not working to calculate score and change value of page element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a calculator file that I am trying to modify to allow me to execute the calculation function more than once at a time.

To elaborate, I can currently use the calculator to get one score at a time however I would like it to accept more than one column of values and spit out a score under each column.

My script is currently not changing the values of the elements used to display them.

Comment: please actually put your code in the question and not links.

Comment: Sorry, changed that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `id="collectSlack[i]"` not a number

```
document.getElementById("collectSlack[i]").value;
```

needs to be

```
document.getElementById("collectSlack["+ i + "]").value;
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I can mark this post answered?